How can i use next-i18next with mongodb and nextjs typescript APP Dir
I'm working on a Next.js application using TypeScript and the App Directory. I want to integrate internationalization (i18n) with next-i18next and use MongoDB for data storage. However, I'm having some difficulties getting everything to work together smoothly.
I followed the next-i18next setup guide and configured my project as per the documentation.
I expected translations to load correctly on all pages, including when navigating between them.
